# Testing a service using mock repository objects

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, repository, moq

I am testing a service within a framework.

In order to initialize the service, I am using mock repository objects.

**ServiceTest.cs**

```
private IRepository _repository;
private IService _service;
private List<Object> _objects;

[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
  _repository = new Mock<IRepository>().Object;

  _service = new Service(repository);

  _objects = new List<Object>()
  {
      new Object { Name = "random", ID = 1 },
      new Object { Name = "not so random", ID = 1},
      new Object { Name = "random", ID = 2 },
      new Object { Name = "not so random", ID = 2}
  };

  //attempt at mocking the repository
  _repository.Setup(r => r.GetObjects(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(_objects.Where(o => o.Name == _objects.Name && o.ID == _objects.ID).ToList());
}

[TestMethod]
public void GetObjects_ReturnObjectsList()
{
    //Arrange
    var name = "random";

    //Act
    var objects = _service.RetrieveObjects(name, 2);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(name, objects.Single().Name);
 }
```

However, when I test the service, I get `ArgumentNullExceptions`. The variables set to the repository method calls return `null`, and eventually throws an error when business logic is run.

**Service.cs**

```
    public List<Objects> RetrieveObjects(string name, int id) 
    {   
      var getObjects = repository.GetObjects(name, id); //getObjects return null

      DoLogic(getObjects); //ArgumentNullException is thrown here

      return getObjects; 
    }
```

I have looked up information on mocking repositories, but seems like I will have a lot to setup just to test. I am wondering if the setup is worth it.

Why am I getting `ArgumentNullExceptions`? Is there a way to test methods that call repositories?

Comment: What are you trying to test? Service or Repository? You are mocking Repository, and asserting what it returns?!

Comment: @lucky3 Oops, I meant service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to Setup what is being tested so in your arrange do something like:

```
var repository = new Mock<IRepository>();
repository.Setup(x => x.GetObjects(It.IsAny<string>()).Returns("whatever getobjects should be returned, maybe a mock object or string");
var service = new Service(repository.Object());
//Continue your test
```

Comment: Please see the update in my question. The `repository` variable is set to a `IRepository` object, rather than var. `new Mock<Repository>()` does not work with `IRepository`.

Comment: Ignore the first line, and just use the mock Setup method to fake the GetObjects call, and then pass the repository object to the service.

Comment: Does it matter that the repository call is in a different `.cs` file altogether? I have setup a mock repository and still am getting `null`. Please see update.

Comment: No it won't matter that the repository is in another file. The difference here is are you creating a unit test or an integration test. If it's the latter, then you probably should reconsider mocking the repository. If it's a unit test and you are testing a solitary unit of code, ie GetObjects(string parameter) then you should mock the repository and return a fake object, like I'm doing in my code. The Returns extension on the Setup should return what you are expecting to be returned.

Comment: +1 this mindset is short and to the point. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
var entity1 = new MyEntity();
var entity2 = new MyEntity();
var entities = new List<MyEntity>{entity1, entity2};

var mockRepository = new Mock<IRespository>();

mockRepository.Setup(r => r.GetObjects("some param")).Returns(entities);

var service = new Service(mockRepository.Object);

service.DoWork("some param");
//continue the test
```

Comment: Does it matter that the repository call is in a different `.cs` file altogether? I have setup a mock repository and still am getting `null`. Please see update.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Inspect your DoLogic method, something there is not right. The setup above should work and return the right data. Check that the "param" is ok as well.

Comment: When `getObjects` is passed into DoLogic, it is `null`. This was the case before the fact. Made no progress so far in that regard. The repository classes have been unit-tested thoroughly and am now testing the services in the framework.

Comment: pls, post the service implementation, i.e. how the repository is passed in.

Comment: after the edit, I do not see where the repository is set up. Look at the example I provided, I do not see mock.Setup anywhere in your code. If you don't set the repository to return what it need to return, the mock will return null.

Comment: See update. I have added an extra parameter to attempt to express where I am running into problems.

Comment: Your code can not compile, the statement in the setup is wrong. _objects do not have Name or Id property. The lambda expression is wrong. Please provide a short but complete example to demonstrate the problem: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can now provide a short complete example, but in doing so, my question has been answered...which is why I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: This was in my answer a long time ago, and re-pointed out in my comment 3 hrs ago as well.

Comment: Your answer was helpful. +1

Answer (score 2):

You should test your SUT (subject under test) in isolation. Don't try to mock existing classes, use interfaces only. That way you won't depend on other objects, who could potentially be buggy. Often you won't be able to setup callbacks and returns of existing classes used as mocks. Mocking interfaces allows you to control and predict the return values.

So in your particular case, you should do as @ianaldo21 proposed, I'd just change first line to:

```
var repository = new Mock<IRepository>();
```

and then do the setup, and pass the repository.Object to Service.

Instead of asserting the state of SUT, you should test the behavior and interactions of SUT with other objects. So you could have something like this:

```
repository.Verify(x => x.GetObjects("test"));
```

That way, you often need much less setting up for the tests.